# Mapping Web API calls to local classes

Tags: windows-runtime, .net-4.5, asp.net-web-api

I'm consuming my ASP.NET Web API service. When I consume a classical web service Visual Studio generates mapping classes for me. Is there some library or approach to map HTTP Web API calls to my classes automatically? I'm consuming from WinRT application, but I would like to move this logic to Portable Library in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are using classes that get returned from your WebAPI URIs. You can just use those same classes on your WinRT application. You would need to deserialize the result of your HTTP call to your object. If your WebAPI project returns the default JSON format, then you can deserialize with JSON.Net